# Can groovy modules access global variables in the jenkinsfile based deployment pipeline, and is it a good idea to do so?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm working with a set of Jenkinsfile based deployment pipelines where each of the steps in the pipeline have been factored out into a library of common groovy modules that are called from the main jenkinsfile.

I've been tasked with integrating JFrog into some (but not all) of the development pipelines.

I was considering setting multiple global variables related to JFrog in the jenkinsfile that could (hopefully) be referenced from within the groovy modules so that we could conditionally implement alternate paths within those modules for the pipelines that need JFrog integration.

Can groovy modules reference variables defined in the main jenkinsfile?  (Assuming this is even a good idea in the first place)

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea. This would create hidden dependencies which make the code harder to understand and could introduce maintenance issues in the future. I think you should pass the JFrog variables as parameters to the functions of your Groovy modules, to make the dependencies clear.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use variables created in the Jenkinsfiles. 
You can just use `def MYVAR` or use `env.MYVAR`; these will be accessible from the rest of your scripts.

Given your use case this is a bad idea - You have multiple Jenkinsfiles, ergo you'll end up maintaining your JFrog related config in multiple places.

A better alternative is to create an object for this configuration in your library code - You could still have multiple alternative paths by passing a single parameter from your Jenkinsfiles.